# In HAML how do I output h1 if this is the home page or div otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I just need a way for my logo to be wrapped in an H1 if this is the home page and if not wrap it in a div so

```
if home

    <h1 id="logo"....

else

    <div id="logo"...
```

Comment: I would abandon whatever SEO ideals led you to think you shouldn't just leave it as an `<h1>` on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- if home
  %h1{:id => "logo"}
- else
  %div{:id => "logo"}
```

Alternatively, if it's really `class` and not `id` you need, you can simplify to:

```
- if home
  %h1.logo
- else
  %div.logo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- if home
  %h1#logo
- else
  #logo
```

(StackOverflow isn't highlighting it correctly though). I generally avoid ids and use classes whenever possible (which would make it `.logo` instead of `#logo`).